# Legal term for (novel?) technique -- "Use of Force", "Tactical Language", or for intel analysts -- if some police repeat some info on licence plates?

Tags: police, language, license-plates

**TL;Dr: The legal issue may be that there is a need to name the law enforcement issue. Is it called "repeating license plates"? Is there a name for the activity, so normal people can describe the act? "NUMB3RS" (TV) does not address/talk about license plates, to my knowledge. Is it official business and been given an official name?**

Regarding `"What is it called?"`, is it possible there is not an agreed/known/specific legal name for the method/technique?

***What is the name for repeating certain licence plates as a police method? What technique runs these repetitions of such information?*** Is it run by some legal argument for [Use of Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_force), or is this what the [PBS Interruptors documentary](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/frontline/film/interrupters/) was about, er the local Motor Vehicles administration running the op all by itself which would be a joke that does not seem likely, maybe https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/546796/tactical-language-from-the-police-is-from-tactical-warfare-from-the-milit "Tactical Language", or just people learning another (probably old, to hex) way to swear? I am asking the technique if it is official, who leads the effort?

I am not asking about how licence plates are made, I am asking about the use of repeating plates, which seems to be a (novel?) policing technique.

For example, the selection of plates shown

> ***Exhibit A, Vehicle A, Vanity Plate "3037" with a "037" at 7 seconds in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whXjR6zkEAY&t=7***
>
> ***Exhibit B, Vehicle B, Vanity Plate "3174" with a "317" at 13 seconds in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcTVV5so-oU&t=13***

is **REPEATED** from

> **I repeated ["317"](https://www.facebook.com/prosody/posts/10101188063333834) and "[037](https://twitter.com/frets/status/1269754495161991168)"** textually and with timestamps on my [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/prosody/posts/10101186248216344) & [Twitter](https://twitter.com/frets/status/1268801701097672704) public social network accounts, in [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=37&oldid=896685144) to
> **[37 (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4882174)** about the deep/questionable stories of 37 official witness testimonies. Given the fairly unique pattern, I can reasonably doubt the statistical probability of any others with that issue/pattern.

What is such repetition called? They're not the same vehicles but always the same plates with "37" every time.

The deliberate meaning/intent/motive of their calculation in showing the plates for a reaction, what is the practice called?

Is any law/organization specifically in charge of these specific ideas/maneuvers, or anyone (any department?) can switch plates at will?

I am focused on finding the technique/law for such experiments. **I think the issue I wish to describe is still difficult to word, the 17/317/037 triggering is experimental?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116791/discussion-on-question-by-prosody-gab-vereable-context-whose-jurisdiction-if-som).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing, legally, as "an attack on someone's writing". The only way in which any use of one person's writing by another could be the subject of legal action would be if it infringed copyright. But individual words, short phrases, and individual numbers are not subject to copyright protection. In theory such things might be protected as trademarks, but that would give protection only if they were being used "in trade", that is, to sell or advertise something, and then only if it is in the same industry or market. But a license plate is not selling anything.

You may have assigned code meanings to particular numbers. Many people have done this before, using many different schemes or codes. It would be hard to demonstrate that a license plate is referring to your coded meaning and not to some other code. But even if the user admitted an intent to reference your use of a particular number, you have no legal cause of action. You might as well ignore such references, because you cannot do anything to prevent them.

Plagiarism is not a crime, nor a tort when there is not copyright or trademark infringement, even if it is openly admitted.

If you could prove harassment or some sort of stalking you might have a case, but nothing you have described (in the question or associated comments) comes close to that. If a police car actually hit yours intentionally or negligently you would clearly have a case, but the plate numbers would be no part of it.

**Response to recent comment**:
The source of authority (which is not the same thing as jurisdiction) to place license plate numbers on police cars is state MV laws and regulations. To the best of my understanding, such numbers are assigned automatically and sequentially, and have no reference whatever to anyone's blog or political statements. No evidence seems to be cited to show otherwise.

The question asks

> What jurisdiction authorizes these reappropriations of my work/writing/speech?

But no one authorizes tjhings that did not happen, and as far as i can see no appropriation occured.  Jurisdictions, by the way, do not authorize things, people and organizations do.

The question asserts:

> For my writing I coined "317" and "037"

but no one can "coin" a number, and people use numbers in many ways. Use of a similar number on a license plate need not be a reference of any sort to a particular blog or writing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116792/discussion-on-answer-by-david-siegel-whose-jurisdiction-if-some-corrupt-cops).